# How add partitions and Incremental Update Statistics to existing table by

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with data. Table was created by this code:

```
    create table [tmp].[Test]
    (
        [RecordId] bigint not null 
                    ,[DateId] int not null
                    ,[CustomerId] int not null 
    );


alter table [tmp].[Test]
add constraint [PK_REP_51671] primary key   ([RecordId])
```

I have partition function and partition scheme:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PartitionByYear_function(int) 
AS RANGE RIGHT 
FOR VALUES(

          20130101
      ,20140101  
      ,20150101  
      ,20160101  
      ,20170101
      ,20180101
      ,20190101
      ,20200101

     ,20210101
     ,20220101
     ,20230101
         ,20240101
         ,20250101
     ,20260101
     ,20270101
     ,20280101
         ,20290101
         ,20300101

      ,20310101
      ,20320101
      ,20330101
      ,20340101
      ,20350101
      ,20360101
      ,20370101
      ,20380101
      ,20390101
      ,20400101 

       ,20410101 
       ,20420101 
       ,20430101 
       ,20440101 
       ,20450101 
       ,20460101 
       ,20470101 
       ,20480101 
       ,20490101 
       ,20500101 

       ,20510101 
       ,20520101 
       ,20530101 
       ,20540101 
       ,20550101 
       ,20560101 
       ,20570101 
       ,20580101 
       ,20590101 
       ,20600101



    );
GO





    CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PartitionByYear_Scheme
    AS PARTITION   PartitionByYear_function
    ALL TO ([PRIMARY])
GO
```

But I don't know how to add partitions to table Test and how to enable Incremental Update Statistics by alter. I know how to add this things to new table by create but how can I add parttitions and statistics to existing table with data by alter?

Comment: What is your version of sql server?

Comment: I have version 2017.

Answer (score 0):

You have everything prepared. You should recreate your table using the partition schema:

```
create table [tmp].[Test]
(
    [RecordId] bigint not null 
   ,[DateId] int not null
   ,[CustomerId] int not null 
)on PartitionByYear_Scheme([DateId]);
```

Comment: I know but I don't want to crate new table, I want to enable partiion and statisctic on table that is already exists and have data inside.

Comment: In that case recreate your cluster index on PartitionByYear_Scheme([DateId])  WITH (STATISTICS_INCREMENTAL=ON).

Comment: I trying with this but it doesn't work                                                                                     alter table [tmp].[Test]
   drop constraint [PK_REP_51674]  


 ALTER TABLE [tmp].[Test] ADD CONSTRAINT [PartitionIndexNew12] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( 
   RecordId
  ,[DateId]
) ON [PartitionByYear_Scheme](DateId) WITH (STATISTICS_INCREMENTAL=ON) ;

Comment: it works, but I got an error 'This type of statistics is not supported to be incremental.'. I'm not very familiar with this feature. ALTER TABLE [tmp].[Test] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [PartitionIndexNew12] 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( RecordId ,[DateId] ) 
WITH (STATISTICS_INCREMENTAL=ON)
ON [PartitionByYear_Scheme](DateId)  ;